# Why としては instead of として

Tags: grammar, particle-は

Please consider the following sentence:

> 呼びかけの言葉**としては**、貴方、が好きですが...
>
> As a form of address, I like 貴方 (then goes on to explain that he means when written in kanji, not hiragana)

According to DBJG として means 'as/in the capacity of', whereas, としては means 'for' (a standard for comparison).

It seems to me that the definition of として would fit the meaning better than としては. Can someone please explain why としては is the correct phrase to use here? Are they both acceptable?

Finally how does it differ from just saying

> 呼びかけの言葉**は**、貴方、が好きですが...

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How does the use of いかんによっては in this question determine one answer over another?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7035/78), and [How does は apply itself to によっては?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8095/78).

Comment: Maybe you should try to understand it as として plus は rather than looking for an English translation for the combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「呼びかけの言葉としては、」の「は」には「限定」、「注目」、「特記」、「取り立て」のニュアンスが付加されます。

「呼びかけの言葉としては、」＝「（その他に、自称の言葉など色々ある中で、）（相手に対する）呼びかけの言葉について限定して言えば」。

「呼びかけの言葉は、」＝限定していない＝他の要素の存在（の可能性）を無視し、単純に返答している。

日本語は、そのとき注目していない話題についても、言外に、他の要素の存在がする可能性を残しておく用心深さを言葉の中に埋め込みます。

英語圏の人々も、誰かを傷つけないためにわざわざ「in my opinion」という言葉を付け加えますね。

そうやって他の意見が存在する可能性を排除しない態度を表明します。日本語でも英語でもpolitenessの考え方は本質的に同じです。

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret
“呼びかけの言葉としては、貴方、が好きですが...”
as

“As far as the addressing word concerns, I like (or prefer) the word, 貴方 (to others such as 君、XXさん、あんた、おたく、旦那、大将),”

and “呼びかけの言葉は、貴方、が好きですが...”
as

“I like ’貴方’ for addressing the other.”