# Meaning of いかんしょ in following sentence

Tags: grammar, dialects, suffixes

In a book called 鉄道員 （ポッポヤ） I read following sentence:

> 俺ァ、ポッポヤだから、身うちのことでなくわけいかんしょ。

(This sentence is really only one sentence, it's his thought on something.)
Notes:
This ポッポヤ is an old man living somewhere in Hokkaido.

Now, I never heard of いかん before, fortunately there was already a question asked for this [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/how-does-the-use-of-%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-in-this-question-determine-one-answer-over-another). But what does the additional しょ　mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 俺ァ、ポッポヤだから、身うちのことでなくわけいかんしょ。

is a collapsed/colloquial way of saying:

> 俺は、ポッポ屋だから、[身内]{みうち}の[事]{こと}で[泣]{な}く[訳]{わけ}に(は)いかないでしょう。

The いかん is 行かん(=行かない), and the いかん in the linked question is [如何]{いかん}.

~わけに(は)いかない means "can't~", "not supposed to~" or "not allowed to~".

The しょ at the end is Hokkaido dialect for [でしょう](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/151485/m0u/) (See naruto's comment).

Comment: FWIW, This ～しょ is a sentence-ending particle used [almost exclusively in 北海道](http://pucchi.net/hokkaido/language/sho.php) (AFAIK).

Comment: @naruto へ～北海道弁・・知りませんでした。

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_21kQWSMqk